# How to render a block from php template

Tags: php, templates, block-editor

forgive me a question that may seem stupid, but has been keeping me busy for hours: I'm trying to insert a gutenberg block into a category php template, but neither the render_block () function nor the do_blocks () function seem to give results.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: There isn't really an API for rendering a block directly into a PHP template. You would need to add one to a post, copy the HTML, and use that in the template.

Comment: Please provide more specific details on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by manually inserting HTML into the template, Thanks.